# push android email settings over the air

Tags: java, android, email, push

I have a mobile device manager service and I want that I am able to push email settings over the air to android devices.

Is it possible to send account settings over-the-air for imap and pop? Similar like you can do in iOS mobile device manager API

Answer (score 0):

Android is an operating system. An operating system has no concept of email account settings. Rather, email applications have email account settings.

You are welcome to assemble a list of all the email applications available for Android -- there are probably a hundred or so, between ones from Google, ones from device manufacturers, and ones from third parties. You can then iterate over that list, contacting the developers of each of those, to see if they offer some means for you to "send account settings over-the-air". I suspect that you will generally find that the answer is "no", but it does not hurt to ask.

Comment: @michelle: I do not know what you mean by "google mail". I am not aware that the AOSP Mail app, or the Gmail app, support "send account settings over-the-air".